# is $(X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ is finite seperable?

Tags: general-topology

is $(X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ is finite seperable? There was a similar question where $X$ is finite and the answer to that is yes. But in the case where $\tau$ is finite, I assume that means the number of subsets of $X$ which are open is finite. If we take the Real numbers and include a singleton as a topology, would that be not seperable?

Comment: For each *non-empty* open set $U\in \tau$, consider a point $x_U\in U$. What can you say about the (countable) set $\{x_U\}_{U\in\tau} \subset X$?

Comment: $D$ is dense iff $D$ intersects every non-empty open subset. Imcluding a singleton in the topology makes no difference whatsoever, except you know for sure that singleton point is in any possible dense set.

Answer (score 1):

Every second countable space is separable. So any space where there are only countably many open sets is separble.

In the real line if you are considering a topology in which every singleton is open then the space is discrete and it is  not separable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for every $O \in \tau\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ we pick $x_O \in O$.

By definition, $\{x_O: O \in \tau\setminus\setminus\{\emptyset\}\}$ is countable (as $\tau$ is) and intersects all non-empty open sets so is dense. So $(X,\tau)$ is separable.

Also note that if $\{p\}\in \tau$ and $D$ is dense we must have $p \in D$.

If $X$ is finite or countable, $X$ itself is dense and countable trivially, so then also $(X, \tau)$ is separable, regardless of $\tau$.